# How to Motorise 42111 Dom's Charger Technic

Tags: technic, motor, remote-control

I just received the [42111 Dom's Charger](https://brickset.com/sets/42111-1/Dom-s-Dodge-Charger) set as a gift, and I was wondering whether it could be motorised and RC controlled? A part list would be great as I don't own any Power Function parts.
Cheers in advance!

[image: Picture of the set 42111]

Answer (score 6):

There are several such MOCs in existence around the Internet:

- https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-42193/Porlock/fully-rc-lego-technic-doms-dodge-charger-model-42111-with-fast-buggy-motor-lights-and-some-changes/#bi
- https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-41973/BrickUrDream/dodge-rc-motorized-42111/#bi
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmYalpTxmIs
- https://racingbrick.com/lego-technic-42111-dodge-charger-rc-mod-with-42095-plus-servo/
- https://buwizz.com/42111-doms-dodge-charger-motorized-and-powered-by-buwizz/
- https://bricksafe.com/pages/Porlock/42111---rc-mod-dons-dodge-charger

Pick your favourite or combine the best features of them together into your own solution :)